# input argument into a matlab function is not being accepted

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
function [x,y,m0,m1,m2,D1,D2,V,b]=engg287_201034628_a2_radar2(r,a)
[num]=readmatrix('a2_radar_data.xls');
r=num(:,2);
a=num(:,3);
g=9.81;
x=r.*cosd(a);
y=r.*sind(a);

N=length(x);        M(1,2)=sum(x);      M(1,3)=sum(x.^2);
M(1,1)=sum(x);     M(2,2)=sum(x.^2);   M(2,3)=sum(x.^3);
M(3,1)=sum(x.^2);  M(3,2)=sum(x.^3);   M(3,3)=sum(x.^4);

b(1,1)=sum(y);
b(2,1)=sum(x.*y);                          
b(3,1)=sum(x.^2.*y);

P=M\b;

error_vec=y-(P(1) + P(2)*x + P(3)*x.^2);
J=sum(error_vec.*error_vec);

m0=P(1);
m1=P(2);
m2=P(3);

r1=(-m1 + sqrt(m1^2 - 4*m2*m0))/(2*m2);
r2=(-m1 - sqrt(m1^2 - 4*m2*m0))/(2*m2);

D1=min(r1,r2);
D2=max(r1,r2);

D=D2;

tanb=-m1-2*m2*D;
b=atand(tanb);

V=sqrt(-0.5*g*(1+tanb)/m2);

figure(1)
plot(x,y);
xlabel('x [m]'),ylabel('y [m]')
title('Conversion from (range,elevation) to (x,y)')
grid

X=linspace(min(D1,D2),max(D1,D2),50);
Y=m0 + m1*X + m2*X.^2;
figure(2);
plot(X,Y,'-',x,y,'gs');
title('Trajectory Estimate')
xlabel('x [m]'),ylabel('y [m]')
end
```

The program receives as input two vectors containing respective measurement streams (r and a).
However when I run the function I get the error message "Unrecognized function or variable 'r'."

I tried to change the function variables names and also put the variable contents before the function. But still same result.

Comment: How are you running this function? By pressing "play" in the MATLAB editor? While you are setting `r` and `a` in the second and third line, the function definition *requires* `r` and `a` to exist to start: `...=engg287_201034628_a2_radar2(r,a)`. You may want to remove `r` and `a` from there.

Comment: I am running the function [x,y,m0,m1,m2,D1,D2,V,b]=engg287_201034628_a2_radar2(r,a)

Comment: By pasting it into the matlab compiler

Comment: r and a take two columns from an excel table

Comment: It is a programming exercise but the function call must be in the format [x,y,m0,m1,m2,D1,D2,V,b]=engg287_201034628_a2_radar2(r,a)

Comment: Can you show the code you use to call this, the entirety of it. A  [mcve] (which is required)

Comment: If you copy-paste `[x,y,m0,m1,m2,D1,D2,V,b]=engg287_201034628_a2_radar2(r,a)` to the command window, then you first need to define `r` and `a` there. It is not magically going to pick up a definition of these variables in a file it hasn’t run yet.